# How do remove agitator from Electrolux Fftw4120sw1

Tags: washing-machine

I have unscrewed the top of agitator but I am unable to remove base. Is there a nut in the center of the agitator? [image][image][image]

Comment: shine a light down there and look for yourself.

Comment: Have you done an internet search to see if there is a parts diagram available online for this washer? Odds are there is and you'll be able to find it on your schedule instead of waiting for someone to do it for you.

Comment: 1. I have looked down there and I cannot confirm if there is a nut or screw to remove the base of agitator.

Comment: 2. I have searched online using the serial number and it turns up very little. I also cannot find a similar agitator to compare it with.

Comment: you have to search on the model number, not serial mumber

Comment: I believe that is the model number. It works in search results. I just can't find anything in removing the agitator.

Comment: I've added photos to show you what I am looking at after taking off top of agitator.

Comment: I had to use a 13 inch screwdriver to get it out. Ridiculous.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't fixed this yet...your answer is yes, there is a Phillips head screw in the middle. You will need a 12" or longer Phillips head screwdriver to remove it.

Comment: Thank you for making an answer out of the comment.